# Creating a WCF Restful service, concurrency issues

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

Hi i am in the process of creating a restful service with WCF, the service is likely to be consumed by at least 500 people at any given time. What settings would i need to set in order to deal with this. Please give me any points and tips, thanks.

Here is a sample of what i have so far;

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

And this is an example of a method being called;

```
    public UsersAPI getUserInfo(string UserID)
    {
        UsersAPI users = new UsersAPI(int.Parse(UserID));

        return users;
    }



    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "User/{UserID}")]
    [WebHelp(Comment = "This returns a users info.")]
    UsersAPI getUserInfo(string UserID);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best approach would be to use:

- `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`
- `ConcurrencyMode.Single`

This will create a new instance of the service class for each caller and saves you from having to worry about multi-threaded, concurrent access to your code, since each request gets its own service class instance (which in itself is single-threaded - it serves only a single caller at a time).

Also, with this approach, you can easily "scale out", e.g. just simply add more servers to handle higher load (servers at your locations, or "in the cloud", e.g. Windows Azure workers).

Using the `ServiceThrottling` service behavior, you can control very easily how many concurrent callers are allowed - this depends on the type and size of your machine.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="Throttling">
     <serviceThrottling 
             maxConcurrentCalls="16"
             maxConcurrentInstances="16"
             maxConcurrentSessions="10" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Those are the defaults for WCF 3.5 - the `maxConcurrentCalls` settings defines how many callers can be handled simultaneously.

Check out the [MSDN docs on Service throttling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, will the same settings still apply if we grew big, and had something like 30000 users?

Comment: +1, good answer. With the above settings you still have to worry about thread safety if you access shared state outside of the service instance. Also, if you don't store mutable state in your service instance, you can use `InstanceContextMode.Single` and `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` for best performance.

Comment: @pmillio: you might need to increase the number of maxConcurrentCalls (that's just the default), or you might need to buy additional servers - but the architecture scales very well

Comment: @Allon Guralnek: a database will typically handle those concurrency issues well, that's why any service should store their state in a database and try to avoid any other state-sharing storage (which gets messy to handle properly)

Comment: I was talking about shared state in objects (e.g. static references, caches, external dependencies such as 3rd party components, etc). Those are sometimes unavoidable, and so care should be taken. I think that the ability to be thread-ignorant only applies to very trivial applications. Also, you usually don't want to take the performance hit of a database roundtrip just to synchronize short-lived shared state.