# concurrent requests in REST service

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, rest, service

I am seeking clarification for working with WCF rest services.

1. How many concurrent request a REST service can handle?
2. Does TimeOut have any dependency on this?
3. How do we implement cache in REST for the connections it
   make;(For Eg. REST service is making a connection to a windows
   object , say Windows 8, to query something; How I can keep this
   connection in cache)?

It would be great, if you can provide some piece of information.

Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: Your answers are basically 1) it depends on the service; 2) it depends on the service; 3) it depends on the service. Unfortunately I think you need to provide much more specific detail if you want to get a useful answer to your questions here, and a thorough answer of all three would probably be very lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

Given the broad nature of your question(s), I think you may need to look into a few aspects of WCF services:

**Instancing**
The instancing behavior (set by using the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode` property) controls how the `InstanceContext` is created in response to incoming messages. By default, each InstanceContext is associated with one user-defined service object, so (in the default case) setting the `InstanceContextMode` property also controls the instancing of user-defined service objects.

**Concurrency**
Concurrency is the control of the number of threads active in an `InstanceContext` at any one time. This is controlled by using theServiceBehaviorAttribute.ConcurrencyMode with the ConcurrencyMode enumeration.

**Throttling**
The `ServiceThrottlingBehavior` class exposes properties that you can use to limit how many instances or sessions are created at the application level. Using this behavior, you can fine-tune the performance of your WCF application.  Use the `MaxConcurrentCalls` property to specify the maximum number of messages actively processing across a ServiceHost class, and the `MaxConcurrentInstances` property to specify the maximum number of `InstanceContext` objects in the service.

The following links provide valuable reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114(v=vs.110).aspx
[Creating a WCF Restful service, concurrency issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698884/creating-a-wcf-restful-service-concurrency-issues)

Comment: Thanks Seymour for this valuable informartion