# Requests are piling up in WCF IIS server

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

We are using `BasicHttpBinding` in a service and also we have set the concurrency mode to multiple and instance context mode to single like below

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single,
 ConcurrencyMode =ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service1 : IService1
```

We have consumed this service in console through reference. We are having an issue that after some time we are seeing messages are pilled in IIS worker process.

For example -> In 1 minute , it is showing as only one thread in worker process in IIS but after some time we are seeing multiple request in IIS?

Could anyone help here like why after some time we are seeing messages queued up in IIS?

Below is binding in config

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Common" 
        closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
```

[image]

Comment: Your code says you've set concurrency to single?

Comment: I have edited the question thanks for pointing it.

Comment: You've set InstanceContextMode to Single (The default value is PerSession) which means "Only one InstanceContext object is used for all incoming calls and is not recycled subsequent to the calls". So it basically creates a queue. If only one request goes awry, never returns or takes a long time to return, all others requests pile up.

Comment: I have gone through multiple articles for example -When the instance mode is single, the single server instance, will be created on the server side, using the same and the only instance, all the clients will be communicated. Here the concurrency mode is Multiple, so the Multiple threads in the server manages all the requests.  it doesn't make sense to me as multiple thread can handle my request at server level due to concurrency but pile up i'm seeing after 1 min interval for same code which is just multiply of two number. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single,
 ConcurrencyMode =ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

> Specifies the number of service instances available for handling calls
>   that are contained in incoming messages:
>   InstanceContextMode.Single -Only one InstanceContext object is used for all incoming calls and is not recycled subsequent to the calls. If a service object does not exist, one is created.
>
> Specifies whether a service class supports single-threaded or
>   multi-threaded modes of operation:
>   ConcurrencyMode.Multiple - The service instance is multi-threaded. No synchronization guarantees are made. Because other threads can change your service object at any time, you must handle synchronization and state consistency at all times. It is your responsibility to guard your state with locks. The service implementation must be thread-safe to use this concurrency mode.

You may try adding `UseSynchronizationContext = false` to your `ServiceBehavior`. If that doesn't help you can try adding `ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete=true` or `false` to your `ServiceBehavior`. I am not sure you can set to true if InstanceContextMode is multiple.

Since with ConcurrencyMode.Multiple  No synchronization guarantees are made, and the default value for UseSynchronizationContext is true, it may be trying to process all calls on the same thread causing the queue.

There could also be some issue with the code you are using to call the service. Without seeing that we would not know.

It could just be taking a little time to spin up a thread for each call?? In your pic, the longest request is only 5.5 seconds. (I know that is long for a simple call.)

This might be insigtful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698956/2016162